# Markdown for obtaining the question title from URL

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

From time to time, I want to cite another thread on MSE **inside a comment** using an inline link. E.g.

> See the thread [Cross product: matrix transformation identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859836/cross-product-matrix-transformation-identity).

In other words, I'll format a link in the form of `[question title](URL)`. However, the `question title` here is a static string. When the actual title changes, this change is not reflected in the link description (although the URL still works).

Is there any markdown that works inside a comment to obtain the title of a MSE question using the URL?

Answer (score 3):

> the question title here is a static string. When the actual title changes, this change is not reflected in the link description

This is true in all cases: future changes to linked question title will **not** be reflected in your posts or comments.

When you paste a bare URL of an SE post into your post, the following happens:

1. The software captures the present title of the linked post.
2. This title is used in the creation of HTML version of your post from the Markdown that you entered.
3. This HTML will be used from that point on, unless *your* post is edited.
4. **If** your post gets edited, the above steps repeat. (So, any updates to the title of linked posts will be captured then.)

The case of comments is different in that comments can't be edited, and they do not fetch the titles of linked posts. However, there is a userscript that automatically gives titles to  SE links in comments:[SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/2378).

Personally, I use a [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#copy) to generate Markdown-formatted URL that I then paste into comments or posts